# Problem with file synchronization for huge amount of files using Ubuntu One in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one

I wanted to use Ubuntu One for the synchronization of the most important Stuff on my Harddisk between two Laptops and my Desktop. So I collected the cluttered files from all three systems to an external drive and then to some folder inside my home directory on my Desktop (~30 GB of data). Then I bought enough space (3 * 20 GB = 60 GB) on Ubuntu One and added the folder to the synchronization.

Unfortunately it does not work. The client prints out the message that it starts synching files (Message in german: "Abgleichen von Dateien wird gestartet ...") for several hours. Nautilus becomes quite slow during that time and finally after those hours I get the message that file synchronization is deactivated (Message in german: "Abgleichen von Dateien ist deaktiviert").

Anyone any idea what's the problem or how I can get further error details?

From u1sdtool -status I get:

```
u1sdtool --status
State: LOCAL_RESCAN
    connection: With User With Network
    description: doing local rescan
    is_connected: False
    is_error: False
    is_online: False
    queues: WORKING
```

Comment: The service is obsolete

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about that, but I have a back up using Deja Dup on my Ubuntu One account (25GB). A full back up of my important files/folders (about 12GB) took me like 12 hours to complete. Yes it is slow, so for you it might take way longer (1.5days?).